# Command is spawning multiple mobs at the same time 1.13.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My summon command summons a random amount of mobs:

```
/execute as @e[tag=testercom] at @e[tag=testercom] if block ~ ~ ~ lime_concrete run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Tags:["testercom","lime"]}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

It's not random. You told the game to make a list of all entities with the "`testercom`" tag, then do everything else as those entities. They then each make a list of all entities with the "`testercom`" tag and do everything else at their location. Then they check for the block and summon the armour stands.

Example: You have one entity tagged "`testercom`" at position A, one at position B and one at position C. Entity A then spawns an armour stand at positions A, B and C, then the second entity does the same, then the third (if the block matches at those locations). So if all three match, you end up with 9 new armour stands.

I recommend reading the [target selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors_In_Java) section of the Minecraft wiki page about commands ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands&oldid=1365953#Target_selectors_in_Java_Edition)). Basically you multiply your command execution on every selector for all matching entities and things like `execute if` filter it. Take particular notice of the `@s` selector, which by itself should go a long way to fixing your problem.